# Global variable in object created from another object

Tags: php, class, global-variables

There are two classes, each one in its own file:

```
<?php
namespace test;

class calledClass {
    private $Variable;

    function __construct() {
        global $testVar;
        require_once 'config.php';
        $this->Variable = $testVar;
        echo "test var: ".$this->Variable;        
    }
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
namespace test;

class callingClass {
    function __construct() {                
        require_once 'config.php';
        require_once 'calledClass.php';
        new calledClass();
    }
}

new callingClass();
?>
```

and simple config.php:

```
<?php
namespace test;
$testVar = 'there is a test content';
?>
```

When I start `callingClass.php` (which creates object `calledClass`), the property `$Variable` in `calledClass` is empty. But when I start `calledClass.php` manually, it reads meaning `$testVar` from `config.php`, and assumes it to `$Variable`.

If I declare `$testVar` as `global` in `callingClass`, it helps - `calledClass` can read `$testVar` from `config.php`.

Can somebody tell me why an object created from another object can't declare variables as global, and use them?

Comment: Besides the fact that this would be incredibly bad practise, and isn't OOP, and a myriad other issues with what you're doing; `$testVar` isn't global inside the callingClass constructor, just a locally scoped variable in that method

Comment: Thank you. What is better way to use config file inside class (besides passing variables as functions' arguments)? `parse_ini_file`?

Answer (score 0):

When including (`include`/`require`) a file inside a function, all variable declarations inside that file get the scope of the function. So `$testVar` is created within the scope of `callingClass::__construct`. **Since you use `require_once`,** it will not be re-created elsewhere inside `calledClass::__construct`! It works when calling only `calledClass` since you're actually including the file for the first time there.

It has nothing to do with OOP at all, just the [rules of function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/476) and your particular use of `require_once`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about `include/require`. But I need more help. When I add `print_r(get_included_files());` into calledClass in my example, it shows 'Array ( [0] => D:\htdocs\test\callingClass.php [1] => D:\htdocs\test\config.php [2] => D:\htdocs\test\calledClass.php ) '. That means config.php is included into calledClass. What interfere with reading variables fron included file inside `calledClass::__construct`?